# which pdf reader support zoom or triming margins in presentation mode?

Tags: pdf

I like to read pdf files in presentation mode. but most of the times its not easy to read text in full screen as text size gets smaller. is there exist any pdf reader that can give me zooming or trim margins in presentation mode.

In normal mode many pdf readers give facility of zoom and trim margins but that does not work in presentation mode.

Comment: Ctrl+Scroll or Ctrl+(+/-) to zoom is not working for me in qpdfview in presentation mode (F12). just now I installed from ubuntu repo

Comment: Excuse me, Ctrl+Scroll or Ctrl+(Up/Down). I'm using qpdfview 0.4.8.99 in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I am using qpdfview 0.4.7 on Kubuntu 14.04 I installed it from repo `sudo apt-get install qpdfview` I tried Ctrl+(Up/Down) also but zooming not working in F12 (presentation mode)

Comment: Could you try install it from daily build ppa https://launchpad.net/~adamreichold/+archive/qpdfview-dailydeb

Comment: upgrading qpdfview is giving me facility to zoom in presentation mode. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**qpdfview** give facility to zoom in presentation mode which was added with version 4.8

Shortcuts used:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>
- or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+MouseScroll

The edge testing package available from developer daily build PPA:

- [ppa:adamreichold/qpdfview-dailydeb](https://launchpad.net/~adamreichold/+archive/qpdfview-dailydeb)

Reference: [lp bug#1264451: Add zoom functionality to presentation view](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qpdfview/+bug/1264451)

Answer (score 2):

### Evince

The default PDF editor with Ubuntu gives you this facility - called Evince

<kbd>F9</kbd> is the shortcut that toggles the content side bar
<kbd>F11</kbd> puts you in full screen mode. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to take you out of fullscreen mode.

When in fullscreen mode, press and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and use the scroll on your mouse to zoom in or zoom out.

Comment: in evince's full screen is not true full screen mode. and Ctrl+scroll dont work in presentation mode in evince

Comment: Alok - then you need to clarify what you mean by "true full screen mode" in your question.  As far as I understand, full screen means the whole desktop showing the PDF.  That is what you see in evince.

Comment: in evince full screen mode is showing button toolbar and menu toolbar. so that is not pure full screen. I dont want to see scroll bars in full screen so I opt for presentation mode

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor note that with recent versions of Evince the toolbar fades after a while if you move the cursor away from it. Also be sure of removing the continuous mode (hit C) so that only one slide is shown at a time (use pgup pgdown to move between slides).